# Drawing triangle on Canvas, when all 3 sides a given, but move it to the middle and rotate it (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have a task to draw triangle on HTML5 Canvas, all 3 sides are given by user(input). But it is drawing on the left side, but I want it to be in the middle and rotated like in picture(look at the white triangle)

Triangle, that I want to get
[image].

Triangle, that I have right now [image].

My code -'

```js
container = document.getElementById("container")
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = canvas.width, cx = cw / 2;
let ch = canvas.height, cy = ch / 2;

const drawTriangle = () => {


//side lengths
let AB = '100'; //document.getElementById("a-side").value;
AB = parseInt(AB);
let BC = '100'; //document.getElementById("b-side").value;
BC =  parseInt(BC);
let AC = '100'; //document.getElementById("c-side").value;
AC = parseInt(AC);



var A = [0, 0]; // starting coordinates
var B = [0, AB];
var C = [];

// calculate third point
C[1] = (AB * AB + AC * AC - BC * BC) / (2 * AB);
C[0] = Math.sqrt(AC * AC - C[1] * C[1]);

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
ctx.moveTo(A[0], A[1]);
ctx.lineTo(B[0], B[1]);
ctx.lineTo(C[0], C[1]);
ctx.fill();
}
drawTriangle();
```

```css
#container, #canvas {
  width: 400px; height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Anna, let me know if my answer has worked out for you

Answer (score 1):

The midpoint of a triangle is easy to calculate (although there are different interpretations of the what the "midpoint" of a triangle is - I'll use the "center of mass" method). You want to shift the midpoint so that it is at the center of the canvas and the coordinate representing this is `(canvasWidth / 2, canvasHeight / 2)`.

Note this example is live; you can try changing the input values. When running the example I recommend you hit "full page".

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const drawTriangle = () => {
  
  // Get user inputs
  let [ AB, BC, AC ] = [ 'a-side', 'b-side', 'c-side' ]
    .map(id => parseFloat(document.querySelector(`#${id}`).value));
  
  // Stop if user input is no good
  if (!AB || !BC || !AC) return;
  
  // Stop if sum of small sides is exceeded by large side
  let [ max, min1, min2 ] = [ AB, BC, AC ].sort((a, b) => b - a);
  if (max > (min1 + min2)) return;
  
  // We define `A` as being at (0, 0), `B` as being a distance `AB`
  // to the east of `A`, and `C` as the point which is a distance
  // `AC` from `A` and `BC` from `B` (and north of both `A` and `B`)
  // Note we do not require a rotate transformation!! We simply
  // define our initial points differently to allow `AB` to be the
  // bottom of the triangle, and parallel to the x-axis.
  
  // Solve for C:
  let Cx = (AB * AB + AC * AC - BC * BC) / (2 * AB);
  let Cy = -Math.sqrt(AC * AC - Cx * Cx);
  
  // Now define our points:
  let [ A, B, C ] = [
    [ 0, 0 ],
    [ AB, 0 ],
    [ Cx, Cy ]
  ];
  
  // Get width+height of canvas. Really we could hardcode these values
  // based on our CSS, but using `getBoundingClientRect` makes this code
  // more maintainable.
  let { width: canvasWidth, height: canvasHeight } = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  let canvasMid = [ canvasWidth / 2, canvasHeight / 2 ];
  
  // Get center of mass of triangle (average x coord, average y coord)
  let mid = [
    (A[0] + B[0] + C[0]) / 3,
    (A[1] + B[1] + C[1]) / 3
  ];
  
  // We'll translate all points. The following can be simplified;
  // I've done things in two steps to make the logic more apparent:
  [ A, B, C ] = [ A, B, C ].map(([ x, y ]) => {
    
    // First shift backwards by the triangle's midpoint.
    // This centers the triangle at the origin (top-left corner)
    [ x, y ] = [ x - mid[0], y - mid[1] ];
    
    // Now shift forwards by half the canvas' size.
    // This centers the triangle at the center of the canvas!
    return [ x + canvasMid[0], y + canvasMid[1] ];
    
  });
  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
  ctx.moveTo(A[0], A[1]);
  ctx.lineTo(B[0], B[1]);
  ctx.lineTo(C[0], C[1]);
  ctx.fill();
  
}

// Changing the inputs redraws the triangle
for (let id of [ 'a-side', 'b-side', 'c-side' ]) {
  document.querySelector(`#${id}`).addEventListener('input', drawTriangle);
}
drawTriangle();
```

```css
#container, #canvas {
  width: 400px; height: 400px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<input id="a-side" type="text" placeholder="A" value="100" />
<input id="b-side" type="text" placeholder="B" value="100" />
<input id="c-side" type="text" placeholder="C" value="100" />
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calculating the relative positions to make the triangle center, We can just keep the coordinates that you have calculated and translate both x and y-axis of canvas with some rotation so that your base will always be centered and parallel to the x-axis.

Look into the code snippet for more comments

```js
const ABInput = document.getElementById("a-side");
const BCInput = document.getElementById("b-side");
const ACInput = document.getElementById("c-side");

canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const cw = canvas.width;
const ch = canvas.height;

let AB, BC, AC;



const drawTriangle = () => {
  setup(); // reset canvas and update sides

  if (!AB || !BC || !AC) return;
  
  
  // ** Calcualte all 3 points [START]
  
  var A = [0, 0];
  var B = [0, AB];
  var C = [];
  // calculate third point
  C[1] = (AB * AB + AC * AC - BC * BC) / (2 * AB);
  C[0] = Math.sqrt(AC * AC - C[1] * C[1]);
  
  // ** Calcualte all 3 points [END]
  
 
  
  // ** Calculation to center triangle [START]
  
  // We are taking AB as base of trianle but this can be dynamic too.
  // And calculating point A's cordinates
  const baseX = Math.floor((cw - AB) / 2); // Point A x cordinate
  const height = C[0];  // This is the height of our triangle
  const baseY = Math.floor((ch - height) / 2 + height); // Point A y cordinate
  
  // ** Calculation to  center triangle [END]
  
  
  
  // Important NOTE:: We dont change A or any other points co-ordinates
  // We can transform our canvas to make it look like we transformed our sides and also changing all points is bit confusing and not that easy to make it flexible


  
  // ** Transforming our canvas [START]
  
  // Translate so that trangle will be at exact center of canvas
  // You can also position your triangle anywhere with translate (flexible)
  // Just think of what should be your point A's cordinates
  // (0, ch) -> bottom left, (cw - AB,  ch) -> bottom right
  // (0, height) -> top left (cw - AB, height) -> top right
  // ((cw - AB)/2, ch) -> bottom center ((cw - AB)/2, height) -> top center etc
  // (baseX, baseY) -> center of the canvas => Our desired position
  ctx.translate(baseX, baseY);
  
  // Rotate 270 to rotate your triangle to make base (AB) parallel to x axis from being parallel to y-axis (From your output)
  ctx.rotate((270 * Math.PI) / 180);
  
  // ** Transforming our canvas [END]
  
  
  
  // Since we translated and rotated canvas
  // The co-ordinates you calculated look like they center the triangle
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(A[0], A[1]);
  ctx.lineTo(B[0], B[1]);
  ctx.lineTo(C[0], C[1]);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
  ctx.fill();
};

function updateSides() {
  AB = parseInt(ABInput.value);
  BC = parseInt(BCInput.value);
  AC = parseInt(ACInput.value);
}

function cleanUpCanvas() {
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // Resetting translate
  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Clearing rectangle

  // Painting our canvas with light gray
  ctx.fillStyle = "#A9A9A9";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
}


function setup() {
  cleanUpCanvas();
  updateSides();
}

ABInput.addEventListener("input", drawTriangle);
BCInput.addEventListener("input", drawTriangle);
ACInput.addEventListener("input", drawTriangle);

drawTriangle();
```

```html
<input id="a-side" type="text" placeholder="A" value="200" />
<input id="b-side" type="text" placeholder="B" value="200" />
<input id="c-side" type="text" placeholder="C" value="200" />

<div id="container">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is a [link](https://codepen.io/vybo-github/pen/ZEevWdq) to try this out